# When I run this code, result is always 24 regardless of what string is. Why?

Tags: c++, string

When I run this code, result is always 24 regardless of what string is. Why?

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    string s = "asdccccc";
    cout << sizeof(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To get the size of a string use `cout << s.size();` (or `cout << s.length();` ... they're synonymous).  When you do `sizeof(s)`, you are not getting the size of the string's payload, you are getting the size of the string object that owns the payload.

Comment: @Caleth I should have known this was a duplicate, thanks.

Comment: Your compilation will be more efficient if you use `#include <string>`, this is a single include file version the unstandard behemoth `bits/stdc++.h`.  In general, only include the headers that actually resolve symbols in your code or header.

Answer (score 4):

A `string` is an object.  By using `sizeof` you are getting the size of the *members* of that object.  One of those members is probably a pointer to the actual string contents, but the size of a pointer is constant no matter what it points to.

Comment: i tried running it on other compilers...answer wasn't 24 but it was still a constant number regardless of the size of the string... so the size of the pointer changes with compiler??

Comment: @ChiragJoshi The definition of the `std::string` class changes with the standard library implementation. The size of pointer doesn't change between compilers, but it does change between different CPU architecture (and x86 supports multiple modes that have differently sized pointers).

Comment: @ChiragJoshi it could be the size of a pointer, especially if one is 32-bit and another is 64-bit.  It could also be the number and type of other members.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this simple example

```
class string
{
    const char* _ptr;
    ....
    ....
public:
   
}
```

When you write `sizeof(string)`, you will get the size of the class, not the size of string literal `_ptr` points to.